# Valgrind error in C code with icd pointers

Tags: c, memory, malloc, valgrind

I inherited a C code.. and one of the lines is below. What is meant by icd here. Is it a keyword or just a name. I could not find it on google anywhere.

```
icd **d1cols = (icd**)malloc(measquant*sizeof(icd *));
```

There after I have:

```
for(i=0; i<measquant; i++){
    *(d1cols + i) = getwtOnAFileColReturnDouble1(fp1, fp2, xx, yy);
}
```

If I print the below line

```
printf("Test 0,0 weight=%.3le\n",*((*(d1cols + 0 ))->wt+0));
```

I am getting below errors in valgrind among other errors:

> Invalid read of size 8
>
> ==45918==    at 0x401945: main (getwtmeasAll_1_main.c:143)
>   ==45918==  Address 0x7e83850 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 896 free'd
>
> ==45918==    at 0x4C27430: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:446)

What is wrong here.

Comment: Please provide a complete example. It is not quite clear where is Line 143 at the moment...

Comment: Also a minimal example, because it's likely that not all of the preceding 142 lines will be relevant.

Comment: `icd` is a type.

Comment: Thanks. I will add a minimal example.  Line 143 is the printf statement. Any more details on icd would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the code is trying to read a portion of memory already deallocated (*free'd*).

`icd` is a data structure defined by the library your code is using. Without additional details there is not much more to be said.

Comment: Indeed the code was trying to access a memory which was already free'ed. I could figure out based on the diff with my previous version.